# Removing / reloading already loaded scripts

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am loading page by ajax. Whole page including `<html> <head> <body>`. 
So I need to call all the scripts which are supposed to be called on page loaded. But browser remembers that some of them had loaded to this windows and he will not execute them again.

How can I delete all loaded scripts?

Or better, how to load entire page, but have some old objects working in background from previous page? For example upload and other communications.

Code:
     this.load = function(adr)
      {
        this.iris();

```
    $.ajax({
          type: 'GET', 
          url:  adr,   
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(data) 
          {    
            $("body").html(html);  
          }
    });
```

edit:
Sorry guys, i have wrote it wrong probably, because your answers are good but solving something else, wchich i could solve by myself. So i will try to tell it in different way.

- I can't save initialization into function or anything else

  Why - because i am working with some template, which have JS in plugins (for forms, callendar..) file for each. 
  Each plugin initialize itself by anonymous function immediately on loaded script.

So when i load HTML by ajax it will not initialize on this new HTML. (for example will not find  and will not add listeners).

Comment: Thanks for -rep, but be hero and tell why :)

Comment: I don't understand why have you downvoted his question, guys. The problem is pretty clear I think.

Comment: @JanKuča I didn't downvote, but I still think the question shows a lack of understanding of javascript's mechanics.

Comment: No argument there but the guy asked for help and explained what his troubles were in a way an experienced developer can grasp the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute a script, you cannot un-execute it and it is kept in the scope even if you replace the whole DOM.

So if you create an object `window.a = new A();` and replace the DOM with `$('body').html(html);`, the object will still be accessible as `window.a`.

Update:

I imagine your script definitions are included in the `<head>` and you have one place where you call them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="script1.js"></script>
  <script src="script2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  ... content ...

  <script>
window.onload = function () {
  // initialization code here
};
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Place the initialization `<script>` in the head as well while storing the `function` in a variable. Then when you load new content replace just the contents of `<body>` and call the function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="script1.js"></script>
  <script src="script2.js"></script>

  <script>
var a = function () {
  // initialization code here
};

var load = function (adr) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url:  adr,   
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
      data = data.exec(/<body[^>]*?>(.*)<\/body>/i);
      $("body").html(data);

      a(); // call the function after each load
    }
  });
};
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="a()">
  ... content ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But i don't understand how to solve problem with scripts. For example there is at least 15 scripts witch handle design, menus, date input.. But they are each in separated file and they are being initialized by anonymous function, so i can't call them, when the page is loaded again by ajax.

Comment: Thank you, but i can't save initialization into function. I have updated my question for better understanding,

Comment: Could you upload your site so that we can see? From what you've written, I think it should work. If there is any JS in the HTML you inject in the page after the AJAX content is loaded, it is executed. You should check the error console.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have found way by myself. I get all script src, then load them as text to array and eval them. But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to 'unexecute' a script is to design it as such in the first place.

This isn't particularly hard, but it takes some knowledge - there is no magic switch to turn this on.

For example...

**index.html**

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
<script> alert(pie); </script>
```

**script1.js**

```
var pie = 'Hello world!';
```

**script2.js**

```
var pie = 'Hello cruel world!';
```

---

So in short, an important pre-requisite would be that you keep all the code inside one single entry point, which you can easily overwrite/remove later on.

Comment: I know this, but i can't modify the scripts which are being loaded. They are part of template. But maybe will work load scripts as text, save them to function and then eval. Will it work? I am not much experienced in javascript. I just read some books but there is just beggining stuff like load text, move with menus...

Comment: Well, what you ask, the 'unload' part, is very vague. In javascript you can remove and overwrite functions, properties and whatnot. You can also 'fix' a 'damaged' DOM (the HTML part). So what you need isn't really out of this world, but it's just vague at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the initialization code directly in the script so that it is executed immediately, put it in a function and then call that function as needed.

Include this once:

```
function initialize() {
    alert('(Re)initializing');
}
```

Then whenever the page is "reloaded", just call `initialize()` again.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is one of thinks which i can't do.